# Custom linux driver for custom Layer 3 protocol

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, drivers, socket, protocols

We're designing a custom communication using a custom physical layer which will be used in a cubesat and I'm looking on how to create the custom layer 3 driver for linux (like ipv4 but not, the headers are completely different).

I took a look in net/af_inet.c to start on how it registers the AF_INET protocol family. However, looking inside net/sockets.c it seems like it's dependent in defined values up to PF_MAX. So I just can't randomly define a new protocol family. Do I just adjust and insert the PF_xxxx before PF_MAX? Or am I missing something? I'd like to refrain from hacking the kernel and stick to loadable modules if possible.

Any materials regarding the topic is welcome though I've already read LDD3, which is how i wrote the device driver for the phy.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the data link layer is also custom and has a different header than ethernet

EDIT: Added block diagram below

The PHY is implemented in an FPGA and connected to the Cortex-A9 via AXI.

[image]

Comment: does this **really** need to happen in kernelmode? I.e. wouldn't you be just as happy with a socket that gives you say, ethernet packets, from which you decode your custom packets in userland software? You would want to be able to do that, anyway, long before implementing this in any operating system – much easier to test.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ideally we want the applications to be able to use the sockets API to make it simpler in terms of programming the applications. Could you elaborate how I can accomplish the routing to the applications if I implement the decoding in userspace?

Comment: that really depends on your software architecture, but it would often be relatively feasible to implement your ethernet-packet-"dewrapper" in one process that itself opens a tun/tap device, to directly write e.g. UDP/IP packets to the other programs.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the data link layer is also custom and not ethernet. Do you think it'll still be possible to do with the approach you mentioned using a tun/tap device? One reason why I want to implement it in kernel mode is the the handling of packets (queueing, priority, etc) which I assume I would need to also rewrite if I implement it in a process in userland

Comment: I must admit I don't know where your data exactly comes from or where it goes, I think a sketch / block diagram might help very much. In my world, I have some userland software that demodulates the waveform from my receiver, and gives me packets full of bits. Then, what do I do with that? I add a header to make that packet look, say, UDP,  and put that packet into a tun/tap device, so that "normal" software can deal with it. I must admit I don't know exactly what things you hope the kernel can do for you?

Comment: and querying/priority: I thought this protocol doesn't exist in the kernel - so *you'll* be the one implementing all this yourself.

Comment: The phy is implemented in an FPGA fabric and connected to the Cortex-A9 via AXI. I've updated the question with a block diagram. I think I understand your approach.. wouldn't a AF_LOCAL work the same but without the additional overhead for ip? 
Re queues,priority: I think the kernel does manage it (https://www.coverfire.com/articles/queueing-in-the-linux-network-stack/) or maybe I understood it wrong